# Using jQuery with Raphael

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael

I have created an image map with Raphael. I want the div containing the Raphael canvas to fade out using jQuery when one of the paths in the image map (path10 in the example below) is clicked. The code below does not work, but am I on the right track?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.onload = function () {
        var R = Raphael("canvas", 1050, 550);
        var attr = {
            fill: "#bbb",
            "fill-opacity": 1,
            stroke: "#222",
            "stroke-width": 0.3,
            "stroke-linejoin": "round"
        };
        path10 = R.path("m 221.63509,150.81487 97.24682,0 0,89.68452 -97.24682,0 0,-89.68452 z").attr(attr);
    };

    path10.node.setAttribute("id","barry");

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#barry").click(function(){
            $("#canvas").fadeOut();
        });
    });

</script>

<body>
    <div id="canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there... this works (tested on Firefox 3.6.8):

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $("document").ready(function() {
        var R = Raphael("canvas", 1050, 550);
        var attr = {
            fill: "#bbb",
            "fill-opacity": 1,
            stroke: "#222",
            "stroke-width": 0.3,
            "stroke-linejoin": "round"
        };
        path10 = R.path("m 221.63509,150.81487 97.24682,0 0,89.68452 -97.24682,0 0,-89.68452 z").attr(attr);
        path10.node.setAttribute("id","barry");

        $("#barry").click(function(){
            $("#canvas").fadeOut();
        });     
    });

</script>

<div id="canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Never ever touch node property.
    path10.click(
will work just fine.

Comment: I know this question is really old,and I appreciate the answers, but I am curious if you know of a way to do this using jquery with multiple variable data that I am getting using JSP and JSTL?

I tried looping and creating multiple divs, but I am having an issue since my first chunk of code is in 1 Raphael Function, and since I apparently cannot create new divs within a script, I had to create a loop, that created divs, with scripts, but that didn't work...

Any idea how to get it working?