# RaphaelJS + jQuery: How to define ID and CLASSES for paths

Tags: jquery, svg

Well, my question is quite simple.

I'm using RaphaelJS to make a country map with hover effects, but how do I get the state ID with hover?

Imagine you have this example path.

```
var path = paper.path('coordinates_here');
```

how do I identify this path with jQuery?
example:

```
    $('#myPathId').mouseenter(function(){
       //do something here
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the built-in event binding of [Raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#events) like:

```
path.mouseover(function (event) {
    //do something
});
```

or you if you really want to use jQuery to do the event binding, you can do:

```
$(path.node).mouseenter(function(){
       //do something here
    });
```

assuming

```
var path = paper.path('coordinates_here');
```

Answer (score 1):

You will find the answer in another post: [How to access id attribute of any element in Raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454593/how-to-access-id-attribute-of-any-element-in-raphael)

By the way: I found it by googling for "raphael path id".