# How to Manipulate a line in Raphael to add/edit points on the line

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have quite a few years experience coding but very minimal javascript and raphael. I've been looking online and in a book I bought on raphael. Part of what I am trying to do is to have a line / path and provide the user the capability to add or edit points to this line.
Something similar to the route on google maps.

I know that a path can be constructed using arrays. I believe those elements can have a unique id that will help accessing them.

I'm thinking something similar to one of the approaches suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130899/raphaeljs-get-all-elements), in particular Adam Moszczyński's approach with regards to separating the drawing from the data; especially as down the road it's likely that this path data will need to be persisted/loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The SVG path syntax is fairly simple if all you want to do is draw straight lines. You really only need to know two commands: `M` to set the location of the first point on the path and `L` to draw a line to the rest of the points.

For example, to draw the following polyline:

```
       [5,2]___________[12,2]
        /                 \
       /                   \
      /                   [13,5]
     /
 [1,10]
```

you would use the following SVG path:

```
M 1 10 L 5 2 L 12 2 L 13 5
```

Note that SVG accepts `,` as number separators and spaces between commands and arguments are optional if they're unambiguous. So the above path can also be written as:

```
M 1,10 L 5,2 L 12,2 L 13,5
```

or even:

```
M1,10L5,2L12,2L13,5
```

But the first form is the most convenient for us to use programatically because it can simply be constructed by joining array elements with the space character:

```
var svgpath = [
    'M', 1, 10,
    'L', 5, 2,
    'L', 12, 2,
    'L', 13, 5
].join(' ');
```

Given this, it's easy to write a function that draws a path in Raphael. There are two ways this can be done:

1. Write your own independent line drawing function/library and use Raphael just as a tool to draw to screen. The simplest is just a function that draws the polyline.

   ```
   function draw_polyline(paper,coords) {
     var first = coords.shift();
     var path = ['M', first[0], first[1]];
     for (var i=0; i<coords.length; i++) {
       path.push('L',coords[i][0],coords[i][1]);
     }
     return paper.path(path.join[' ']);
   }

   draw_polyline(paper,[[1,10],[5,2],[12,2],[13,5]]);
   ```
2. Write it as an extension to Raphael. The function is exactly the same but behaves as if it's part of Raphael:

   ```
   Raphael.fn.polyline = function (coords) {
     var first = coords.shift();
     var path = ['M', first[0], first[1]];
     for (var i=0; i<coords.length; i++) {
       path.push('L',coords[i][0],coords[i][1]);
     }
     return this.path(path.join[' ']);
   }

   var paper = Raphael('div',640,480);
   paper.polyline([[1,10],[5,2],[12,2],[13,5]]);
   ```

Note that the simple function above simply draws the line from the given coordinates. To add or remove points to the line you'll have to redraw the path by calling the polyline function with the updated coordinates. This works but is not exactly ideal since you'll have to keep track of the old line and delete it when you draw the new line.

A better solution is to have the line update itself. To do this we'll need to refactor the code above to separate the svg path generation from the drawing function:

```
function polyline_path(coords) {
  var first = coords.shift();
  var path = ['M', first[0], first[1]];
  for (var i=0; i<coords.length; i++) {
    path.push('L',coords[i][0],coords[i][1]);
  }
  return path.join(' ');
}
```

then the Raphael implementation is simply:

```
Raphael.fn.polyline = function (coords) {
  return this.path(polyline_path(coords));
}
```

Now we can add some functionality to the Raphael path object that represents our polyline:

```
Raphael.fn.polyline = function (coords) {
  var path = this.path(polyline_path(coords));
  path.coords = function(xy) {
    if (!xy) {return coords} // return coordinates if no arguments given

    coords = xy;
    path.attr('path',polyline_path(coords)); // otherwise update svg path
  }
  return path;
}
```

Now we can use it like this:

```
var route = paper.polyline([[1,10],[5,2],[12,2],[13,5]]);

// Add point to route:
route.coords(route.coords().push([15,10]));
```

That's still a bit ungainly but you get the idea. You can use this basic concept to implement more advanced API. For example, it would be nice if the polyline object implement most of the Array methods so you can simply do:

```
route.push([15,10]); // add point to route
route.shift(); // remove point from beginning of route
route.splice(1,1,[5,3]); // modify the second point
// etc..
```

It's really up to you how far you want to take this.

Comment: Thanks, I would vote you up - but my reputation is too low!
I did find in your examples a couple of quirks. I had to change:
`return path.join[' '];` to `return path.join(' ');`

Comment: Also, for some reason, I got various errors when trying to do `route.coords(route.coords().push([15,10]));` to get it to work for me I used:
`var route = paper.polyline2([[121,110],[135,122],[132,112],[113,105]]);
// Add point to route:
var z = route.coords();
alert('changing coords');
z[1][1]=233;
route.coords(z);
alert('adding coords');
z.push([115,140]);
route.coords(z);
'
Hopefully this'll help me move forward a lot