# How can one use jQuery together with Raphael JS?

Tags: jquery, raphael, javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var canvas = $('#canvas');
        var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas'), 500, 500);

        var circ = paper.circle(250, 250, 40);
        circ.attr({fill: 'green', stroke: 'none', 'stroke-width': 15, 'stroke': 'red', 'fill-opacity': .5});
        var text = paper.text(250, 250, 'Bye Bye Circle!');
        text.attr({opacity:0, 'font-size': 12}).toBack();

        circ.animate({ 'transform': 'r90T100,0'}, 2000);

        circ.node.onclick = function() {
            text.animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
            circ.animate({opacity: 0}, 2000, function() {})
        };
    });
```

• How would I be able to, for instance, replace the second line? $('#canvas') does not seem to work.

• Also circ.node.onlick: Is it possible to accomplish a handler with jQuery? How do I access the circ node with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JQuery with Raphael](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613636/using-jquery-with-raphael)

Comment: No need for jquery in either, or are you specifically needing jquery for some reason and these are just smaller examples ? Otherwise, just Raphael("canvas",500,500); For the 2nd,  circ.click( handler ).